# Installed Ubuntu in VMware Player, Black side bars / broken GUI

Tags: unity-dash, vmware

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 in VMware Player and have came up with a black sidebar, missing icons, a pretty broken GUI. Everything works just fine though. I am able to run Firefox and open termainal and all that good stuff just fine, it's just that

I can SEE them on the sidebar. I have to open up a seperate window on Windows with a picture of the Ubuntu 12.10 desktop in order for me to know what to click on, but once I do click on it, it's pretty much smooth sailing from there(not counting closing Firefox and several other things).

Again, everything works just fine, but when it comes to the sidebar, the GUI, the dashboard (get a completely black screen for when I open dash board), they come up as completely black, broken (visual tears and what not), and hoving over them just brings up a big black bar (assuming it's the "zooming" in of the icon, but it just shows a black bar of where the icon should be). I'm not exactly sure what so do to get this to work (to fix the GUI), any ideas as to what I may do to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You should disable **3D graphics acceleration**.

- Firstly, shutdown Ubuntu.
- Then go to **Virtual Machine Settings** → **Hardware** → **Display** → un-check **Accelerate 3D graphics**.
- Lastly, start the Virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar using a kvm virtual machine. Maybe it is related to the fact that ubuntu detects the display as a laptop display.

I fixed it by resetting the theme. Go to system settings/appearance and select ambiance (default). When selecting high contrast, it pretty much goes black again.

Answer (score 0):

Shutdown the Ubuntu VM machine, then click on:

**VM** → **Setting** → **Hardware** → **Display** → un-check **Accelerate 3D graphics** → OK

Start the machine again and check.