# Ubuntu unity not appearing in VMware

Tags: 14.04, unity, xfce, vmware

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.4 on my [VMware](http://www.vmware.com/). (It opens in command line. Using `startx` enters me into GUI mode.)

> **Problem:** I cannot see side panels and menu bar:

[image: Unity not appearing]

I took the following steps so far:

- [disabled Hyper V](https://superuser.com/questions/519991/vmware-player-is-not-working-after-installing-hyper-v-on-windows-8-pro),
- [installed ubuntu desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320334/how-do-i-install-the-unity-desktop-environment-on-ubuntu-studio-13-04-xfce),
- [installed VMware tools](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1017687),
- [installed unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/562011/just-installed-some-updates-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-on-vmware-now-desktop-wont-sh),
- [disabled 3D graphics accelaration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216017/installed-ubuntu-in-vmware-player-black-side-bars-broken-gui)

Is there anything more required?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling?

Comment: hmm, but why does it require reinstalling? :( That will be the last resort.

Comment: it is sad, but something could have gone wrong with the installation, who knows. Just a possibility. Also, did running from the disk (to get it to install) bring up the GUI? (the full desktop gui, not just a scaled down install)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [problem was with **easy installation**](https://www.computersnyou.com/371/how-to-disable-easy-installing-feature-in-vmware-workstation/)  of VMware. I built a new Virtual machine `(without allowing VMware to install the OS on it's own)` and installed the OS *manually*. After that [adjusted the resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691781/how-to-set-maximum-fullscreen-in-vmware).

Now there is no display issue.